# how to achieve parllel calls response in play-scala reactjs seed

Tags: reactjs, scala, rest, playframework

I am using **play-scala** with **ReactJS(in public directory)** application. I have around 100 Rest API's in my project. Some of the API's taking more than 10 to 15 minutes to give the response, Because that API handling the bulk data. When I'm using this API's I'm unable to use another API until that API completed.

I'm using `async` to achieve this, But still It's not resolved.

```
  def get() = validate.actionType.async { request =>

    getAll()
  }
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: use a queue and process it async?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I have updated my question please check it

Answer (score 1):

There could be two reasons:

1. You are in dev mode. The dev mode uses 1 thread.
2. You are doing request from the same browser: [Are Play framework controller actions synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331646/are-play-framework-controller-actions-synchronized)

Comment: I'm checking Andriy